# Launch another app in Android but keeping the old one in the queue

Tags: android

If in my Android app I do this:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent();
          intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
          intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          intent2.setClassName("com.andrew.apollo", "com.andrew.apollo.activities.MusicLibrary"); 

          getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent2);
```

Then Android actually runs the new app, but I would like to keep my old app in the queue, so if I tap 'back' button, I go to the old app, or even the old app is still in the queue when I tap 'home' button.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Actually, it was a finish() that I didn't remember I had written in the code. I removed it and now it works as expected. Thank you to everyone.

Comment: Ummm. That's default behaviour for launching an intent. Try removing your FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK from the intent and seeing what happens

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work meaning....? What's the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: The old app disappears from the queue and then I only have the new app when I tap home button, so the same behaviour as before.

Comment: are you calling `finish()` in your first app?

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you launch a new application or activity from current Activity and don't call **finish()** method for current Activity it will remain on stack until Android OS is desperately running out of memory.

It may happen in low memory devices that it gets destroyed (in your case i guess), otherwise it will go to its **"Stop"** state and when you tap 'back' button it will **restart** automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The same code is working fine for Me. You must be calling finish(); after launching intent.